How do I select equipment for a load management system of EV chargers?
In a student project, I need to design a EV-charging system for a domestic high-storey building. As there is not enough loading(the charging stations are connected to tenant supply of multiple floors), and the usable loading fluctuates in time, I have decided to install a load management system.
In my current design, the load management system would first senses the total current available at the moment by sensing the ampere provided by the CT box through an analog input. It would then sense the total EV chargers in use at the moment through a digital input, and divide the current available by the total amount of EV chargers to calculate the output load for each EV charger. If the output load exceeds the full load of the EV chargers, the amount is set to the full load current and sent to the EV chargers through an analog output. Else the output signal would be sent to the EV chargers directly through an analog output.
How do I select the correct equipment for such system? What A/I, D/I, A/O equipment can be selected for this system? Do I need a specific type of EV chargers as well?

"...total current available at the moment...". Can you elaborate on this? Is the current always present / flowing?

@AJN I presume they use the load available from the service and then subtract the measured use from that to get to the available load for EV charging
